# Macro VBA to save a copy of specific cells in a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of values from A2 to B6 and I wish to save those cells in a new workbook. The destination folder is in (C:) and has the name of "Products" so the new workbook must be inside this folder.

Also, as a Plus, It would be amazing if before saving the file, the macro could ask me through an InputBox what file name I want to give the new excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do the work:

```
Sub CopyToNewWb()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb_New As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wbstring As String
Dim input_file_name As String

input_file_name = InputBox("Enter file name", "Enter new workbook file name") 'Create input box

wbstring = "C:\Products\" 'Set workbook path
Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:=wbstring & input_file_name & ".xls", FileFormat:=56 'I would add date here if user enters the same name twice...

Set wb_New = ActiveWorkbook

wb_New.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B6").Value = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B6").Value 'Copy Range from wb to new workbook

End Sub
```

---

For different file format numbers, please see the link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat

| Name | Value | Description | Extension |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xlCSV | 6 | CSV | *.csv |
| xlExcel8 | 56 | Excel 97-2003 Workbook | *.xls |
| xlExcel9795 | 43 | Excel version 95 and 97 | *.xls |

Comment: Hey, thanks in advance for the answer. For some reason, the code is creating conflict in this line:  Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:=wbstring & input_file_name & ".xlsx"

Comment: I think I missed the last "\" in the path. You'll also get an error if you have a file with the exact name already or if it's opened. I assume you have permission to save in the folder location.

Comment: Lovely. Glad to hear it worked out :)!! Happy coding.

Comment: The code is already running good, but I would like to add something else.
For example, I would like to save the new file in an excel version 97-2003. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Np! See updated answer. I also changed the file extension to `.xls`. If you change your worksheet to a new fancy colour and save, you will get an notification that the color is not supported.

Comment: Once again works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Lovely to hear :D, just fun to help!